# Finding unique emails comparing two columns in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two email lists that I want to compare. One has 160.000 email adresses. The other has 10.000. What I wan't to find out is how many of these 10.000 are not present in the bigger list.

I have tried using different formulas but nothing seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that your big list of email addresses is in column A, and goes from A1 to A160000. The smaller list is in column B, and goes from B1 to B1000.

A simple `countif` formula should answer your question. Put this formula in C1, and drag it down to C1000:

`=COUNTIF(A:A,B1)`

This formula returns the number of times the value in cell B1 appears in the range A:A, which just means all of column A. You could replace A:A with A1:A160000, too.

Any email addresses in column B will have a "0" next to them in column C if they do not appear in column A. If you want the complete list of email addresses that are unique to the smaller list, just filter columns B and C (find the "Filter" button under the "Data" tab) and select "0" for column C's filter and all other values will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide that much info so it's very hard for me to say what will work for you, but something like have worked for me in the past:

`=IFERROR(INDEX('Sheet2'!A:A,MATCH(A1,'Sheet2'!D:D,0)), "No Duplicate")`

I'll break this down:

`MATCH(A1,'Sheet2'!D:D,0)` is to find exact match using `A1` and `Sheet2!D:D` is the should be the column of your 160,000 email addresses, and `0` indicated exact matches only.

`INDEX('Sheet2'!D:D,MATCH(A1,'Sheet2'!D:D,0)` will return the email address in Sheet2 D:D that matches (not needed in your case).

Finally `IFERROR` will provide you with "No Duplicate" or the email addresses that it match.

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but hopefully this will work for you.